# Same code is selecting columns in one section and rows in another. Why?

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I am attempting to select out certain columns from a dataset. I've been using:

```
dfx <- dfx[c(1,2,3,4)]
```

This has worked previously within this same data set and correctly selects out columns 1-4. But 20 lines later when I use:

```
dfy <- dfy[c(1,31)]
```

It selects rows 1 and 31. What's going on here, and how can I make it stop.

Thanks.

Comment: You can check whether you have a `data.frame` or something else.  To be safe try `dfy[, (c(1, 31)]` i.e. check the `str(dfy)` and `str(dfx)`

Comment: For a dataframe you select columns `df[,"like this"]` and row `df["like this",]`

Comment: @Hack-R For a data.frame, the OP's method would also work for selecting columns

Comment: @akrun I know but it's a bad practice

Comment: @Hack-R In some cases, it is preferred.  For example, if you want to get a single column data.frame, `df[, 1]` returns a vector unless you add the drop=FALSE argument

Comment: Somewhere in those twenty lines of code my data.frame became a combo data.frame/data.table, and that's what was making things screwy. Thank you both for the help.

Comment: could be `merge` doing it